# ¿guardar objeto dentro de otro sin sobrescribir? javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes comunidad
estoy tratando de crear un objeto dentro de otro en javascript de está manera

```js
{
  "data": {
    "toFix": [{
        "id": "e9a4b5f63b54",
        "location": "Johan, Esteban, Higuita",
        "data": "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"partial_match\":0,\"type\":\"locality\",\"lat\":4.5350004,\"lng\":-75.6756888,\"locality\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_2\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_1\":\"Quindio\",\"country\":\"Colombia\",\"countrycode\":\"CO\",\"formatted_address\":\"Armenia, Armenia, Quindio, Colombia\"}"
      },
      {
        "id": "0ce3078986be",
        "location": "Cesar, Augusto, Celis",
        "data": "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"partial_match\":0,\"type\":\"locality\",\"lat\":4.5350004,\"lng\":-75.6756888,\"locality\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_2\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_1\":\"Quindio\",\"country\":\"Colombia\",\"countrycode\":\"CO\",\"formatted_address\":\"Armenia, Armenia, Quindio, Colombia\"}"
      },
      {
        "id": "2db4488babcb",
        "location": "Hector, Narvaez",
        "data": "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"partial_match\":0,\"type\":\"locality\",\"lat\":4.5350004,\"lng\":-75.6756888,\"locality\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_2\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_1\":\"Quindio\",\"country\":\"Colombia\",\"countrycode\":\"CO\",\"formatted_address\":\"Armenia, Armenia, Quindio, Colombia\"}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Pero la idea es que no tome el ultimo valor si no que se vaya agregando
tengo esté fragmento de código donde resume lo que trato de hacer

```js
var valuesToLocalStorage = new Object();
valuesToLocalStorage['data'] = new Object();
valuesToLocalStorage['data']['toFix'] = new Object();
let toFix = {'id': 50, 'location': 'colombia', 'data':'medellin - antioquia'};
valuesToLocalStorage['data']['toFix'] += toFix;
console.log(valuesToLocalStorage)
```

Comment: No se añaden cosas a un array usando `+=`, se añaden usando `.push(nuevoObjeto)`.  La [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) está para usarla, te recomiendo que te acostumbres a ella. Por cierto, tampoco se crea un array como `new Object()`... se crea como array, o asignándole directamente un array vacío: `valuesToLocalStorage['data']['toFix'] = [];`. De nuevo, la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) te habría indicado la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: Déjanos saber si alguna de las respuestas o comentarios solucionó tu problema marcándola con el check y con el upvote del lado izquierdo. En caso contrario, deja un comentario para tratar de darte otras soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de que tienes un objeto inicial, lo importante es asignarlo a una variable y saber en que lugar se debe agregar el nuevo objeto, *(en tu caso en el array `toFix`)*. Finalmente se agrega el nuevo objeto mediante `push()`.

```js
//Asignar el objeto original a una variable
let objetoInicial = {
  "data": {
    "toFix": [{
        "id": "e9a4b5f63b54",
        "location": "Johan, Esteban, Higuita",
        "data": "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"partial_match\":0,\"type\":\"locality\",\"lat\":4.5350004,\"lng\":-75.6756888,\"locality\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_2\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_1\":\"Quindio\",\"country\":\"Colombia\",\"countrycode\":\"CO\",\"formatted_address\":\"Armenia, Armenia, Quindio, Colombia\"}"
      },
      {
        "id": "0ce3078986be",
        "location": "Cesar, Augusto, Celis",
        "data": "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"partial_match\":0,\"type\":\"locality\",\"lat\":4.5350004,\"lng\":-75.6756888,\"locality\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_2\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_1\":\"Quindio\",\"country\":\"Colombia\",\"countrycode\":\"CO\",\"formatted_address\":\"Armenia, Armenia, Quindio, Colombia\"}"
      },
      {
        "id": "2db4488babcb",
        "location": "Hector, Narvaez",
        "data": "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"partial_match\":0,\"type\":\"locality\",\"lat\":4.5350004,\"lng\":-75.6756888,\"locality\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_2\":\"Armenia\",\"administrative_area_level_1\":\"Quindio\",\"country\":\"Colombia\",\"countrycode\":\"CO\",\"formatted_address\":\"Armenia, Armenia, Quindio, Colombia\"}"
      }
    ]
  }
}

//Mostrar lo que contiene el objeto inicialmente
console.log("Información inicial");
console.log(objetoInicial);

//Agregar la nueva información al objeto toFix 
//que está dentro de data 
//y data está dentro de objetoInicial
objetoInicial.data.toFix.push({'id': 50, 'location': 'colombia', 'data':'medellin - antioquia'});

//Mostrar el objeto inicial con el nuevo objeto agregado
console.log("Información con el nuevo objeto agregado");
console.log(objetoInicial);

//Ya puedes hacer lo que necesites con todo el objeto
```